# Printing a list of list without brackets in python

Tags: python, list

I have a list of list that I want to display as a string. This list:

```
my_list = [[7, 'd'], [3, 's']]
```

I want to display without the brackets and commas like this:

```
7d 3s
```

How?

Comment: `list` is a bad variable name since you are shadowing the built-in `list`. I changed it to `my_list`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> my_list = [[7, 'd'], [3, 's']]
>>> ' '.join('{0}{1}'.format(x, y) for x, y in my_list)
7d 3s
```

The above solution is best for the specific case of any two elements but here is a more general solution which works for any number of elements in the sublist:

```
>>> ' '.join(''.join(map(str, sublist)) for sublist in my_list)
7d 3s
```

Answer (score 2):

I would come to this short answer:

```
' '.join(str(a)+b for a,b in my_list)
```

Comment: At least use `str`, the `\`\`` feature has been removed from the language in Python 3.